# How to know if the append function is filling the properties of a NSObject

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Swift 2.0 Alamofire 2.0 Xcode 7 IOS 9

I have the next function which calls the API and retrieves the friend list in JSON format, convert the list in dictionary and append it to the Friendship NSObject

```js
func GetFriends(completionHandler: ([FriendShip]?, NSError?) -> ()) {

    Alamofire.request(Router.GetFriends(Test().getUserId())).responseJSON { (_, _, result) in

      var friends = [FriendShip]()

      switch result {
        case .Success(let json):
          if let responseObject = json as? [String: AnyObject], let hits = responseObject["hits"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            for dictionary in hits {
              friends.append(FriendShip(dictionary: dictionary))
              print(friends)
            }
            completionHandler(friends, nil)
          }
        case .Failure(_, let error):
          completionHandler(nil, error as NSError)
      }

    }
```

the result of **print(dictionary)** is :

```js
["_id": 546a6ef98e6df97032266, "friend": {
    "_id" = 546a4b3e1f8d2c2630dd2;
    name = "Daniela";
    profileImageUrl = "https://api-static/profile/546a4b3e1f8d2c2630dd2.1.jpg";
    statusTxt = "";
}]
["_id": 546a6f988e6df97032266, "friend": {
    "_id" = 546a4ba51f8d2c2630dd2;
    name = "Mara";
    profileImageUrl = "https://api-static/profile/546a4ba51f8d2c2630dd2.1.jpg";
    statusTxt = undefined;
}]
["_id": 546a70a18e6df97032266, "friend": {
    "_id" = 546a4bd61f8d2c2630dd2;
    name = "Alejandro";
    profileImageUrl = "https://api-static/profile/546a4bd61f8d2c2630dd2.1.jpg";
    statusTxt = "Marty";
}]
["_id": 546a715d8e6df97032266, "friend": {
    "_id" = 546a4be01f8d2c2630dd2;
    name = "Pedro";
    profileImageUrl = "https://api-static/profile/546a4be01f8d2c2630dd1.1.jpg";
}]
```

classes Friendship and User

```js
 class FriendShip: NSObject{

      var id: String?
      var userId: String?
      var user: User?
      var friendId: String?
      var friend: User?
      var date: NSDate?

      init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]){

        id        = dictionary["id"] as? String
        userId    = dictionary["userId"] as? String
        user      = dictionary["user"] as? User
        friendId  = dictionary["friendId"] as? String
        friend    = dictionary["friend"] as? User
        date      = dictionary["date"] as? NSDate

      }

      override var description : String {
        let friendString = friend!.name != nil ? friend!.name! : "nil"
        let urlString = friend!.profileImageUrl != nil ? friend!.profileImageUrl! : "nil"
        return "Friendship:\nfriend = \(friendString),\nurlString = \(urlString)"
      }
}

class User: NSObject{

      var id: String?
      var name: String?
      var statusTxt: String?
      var profileImageUrl: String?

      init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]){

        id              = dictionary["id"] as? String
        name            = dictionary["name"] as? String
        statusTxt       = dictionary["statusTxt"] as? String
        profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
      }

      override var description : String {
        let nameString = name != nil ? name! : "nil"
        let profileImageUrlString = profileImageUrl != nil ? profileImageUrl! : "nil"
        return "Friendship:\nname = \(nameString),\nprofileImageUrl = \(profileImageUrlString)"
      }

}
```

How can I know/view/print if the friends.append function is working properly and its filling OK all the properties of the Friendship NSObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need a way to print / debug the contents of your `Friendship` class.

`NSObject` implements the `NSObjectProtocol` which has a computed property `description`. That property returns a String that represents the contents of the class. It is the text you see when you print an object. So your `Friendship` class already inherits this `description` protocol from `NSObject`. But in your case it only prints the class name, because that is the default implementation.

So if you want to have a more meaningful description of your class, you have to override the description property:

```
class Friendship: NSObject {
    var name: String?
    var age: Int?

    override var description : String {
        let nameString = name != nil ? name! : "nil"
        let ageString = age != nil ? String(age!) : "nil"
        return "Friendship:\nname = \(nameString),\nage = \(ageString)"
    }
}
```

I don't know what your actual `Friendship` class looks like, so I made my own, very simple class that only contains a name and an age.

So now when you have 2 instances of `Friendship` (one filled and one empty) and you print them, you can see the contents of that objects:

```
let friendship1 = Friendship()
friendship1.name = "John"
friendship1.age = 34
print(friendship1)

let friendship2 = Friendship()
print(friendship2)
```

Prints:

```
Friendship:
name = John,
age = 34

Friendship:
name = nil,
age = nil
```

**UPDATE**

In your case the overridden description vars should look like this:

```
    class FriendShip: NSObject{

    var id: String?
    var userId: String?
    var user: User?
    var friendId: String?
    var friend: User?
    var date: NSDate?

    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]){ 
        id        = dictionary["id"] as? String
        userId    = dictionary["userId"] as? String
        user      = dictionary["user"] as? User
        friendId  = dictionary["friendId"] as? String
        friend    = dictionary["friend"] as? User
        date      = dictionary["date"] as? NSDate

    }

    override var description : String {
        let friendDescription = friend != nil ? friend!.description : "nil"
        let userIdString = userId != nil ? userId! : "nil"
        return "Friendship:\nfriend = \(friendDescription),\nuserId = \(userIdString)"
    }
}

class User: NSObject{

    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var statusTxt: String?
    var profileImageUrl: String?

    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {  
        id              = dictionary["id"] as? String
        name            = dictionary["name"] as? String
        statusTxt       = dictionary["statusTxt"] as? String
        profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
    }

    override var description : String {
        let nameString = name != nil ? name! : "nil"
        let profileImageUrlString = profileImageUrl != nil ? profileImageUrl! : "nil"
        return "User:\nname = \(nameString),\nprofileImageUrl = \(profileImageUrlString)"
    }
}
```

You can test it:

```
// test empty object
let friendship = FriendShip(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]())
print(friendship.description)

// test correct object
let user = User(dictionary: ["name": "John", "profileImageUrl": "http://image.com"])
let friendship2 = FriendShip(dictionary: ["friend": user, "userId": "1"])
print(friendship2.description)
```

Prints

```
Friendship:
friend = nil,
userId = nil

Friendship:
friend = User:
name = John,
profileImageUrl = http://image.com,
userId = 1
```

Comment: Great Joern, but as you can see in the edited code, the issue Im having is the point that the Friendship NSObject have 2 properties, friend and user, that are references of the user NSObject and I don't know how to fill these properties in the function **friends.append(FriendShip(dictionary: dictionary))** and how to print the complete FriendShip NSObject with the values of the user NSObject too

Comment: To also print the values of the `User` properties in your `Friendship` class you also have to override the the `description` property in the `User` class. Then you automatically get the values for those two properties when you call `print(friendship)`

Comment: sorry, but if I set the **let nameString = name != nil ? name! : "nil"** in the override function in the user object and **let friendString = friend.name != nil ? friend.name! : "nil"** in the override function in the friendship object, this last declaration throughs a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error

Comment: That is because in my example the properties are Optionals (like `var name: String?`) and you use unwrapped properties (like `var name: String!`). So you tell the compiler that those properties never will be nil. But you cannot guarantee that because the initialization with the dictionary might fail and then your app crashes. In other words, you should make your properties Optionals (change the `!` to `?`

Comment: sorry Joern but even changing the unwrapped by optionas the issue persists

Comment: Can you please add the updated code with the overridden description properties to you answer?

Comment: In the `FriendShip.description` you should not access the `User` properties, but only call `description` on the user. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93114/discussion-between-edu-and-joern).